# If $B$ is in $SPACE(n^2)$ and $A \leq_p B$ then so $A$ will be in $SPACE(n^2)$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

We know that if $B$ is in $P$ and if $A \leq_p B$ then $A$ is in $P$ too.

If $B$ is in $SPACE(n^2)$ and $A \leq_p  B$ then so $A$ will be in $SPACE(n^2)$?

I think that the answer to this question is true, because if $A\in P$ then $A \in PSPACE$, and then $A$ could be in $SPACE(n^2)$. I doubt my answer because of that $(n^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ may or may not be in $\mathrm{SPACE}(n^2)$.

Any language $A\in\mathrm{P}$ can be reduced be reduced to any nontrivial language $B\in \mathrm{SPACE}(n^2)$ in polynomial time.  Fix your favourite strings $x_\mathrm{yes}\in B$ and $x_{\mathrm{no}}\notin B$ ("nontrivial" means that $B$ is neither $\emptyset$ nor $\Sigma^*$, so both of these strings exist). The reduction is to determine if the input is in $A$; if so, map it to $x_\mathrm{yes}$; if not, map it to $x_\mathrm{no}$.

This is true regardless of whether $A\in\mathrm{P}\cap\mathrm{SPACE}(n^2)$ or $A\in\mathrm{P}\setminus\mathrm{SPACE}(n^2)$.

To get some intuition, it might help to look at it in another way. To show that $A\in\mathrm{SPACE}(n^2)$, you'd want to show that the algorithm "Reduce to $B$, then decide $B$" runs in quadratic space. However, the reduction from $A$ to $B$ might blow up the length of the instance by any polynomial amount.  For example, It could map a instances of length $n$ to ones of length $n^2$. So, now, if you try to decide $A$ by first reducing to $B$, you'll need space $(n^2)^2 = n^4$ to solve  the instance of $B$. Or the reduction itself might take more than $n^2$ space.